Hide WooCommerce shipping methods based on product variation attribute
I'm trying to hide WooCommerce shipping methods based on variations chosen by the user.
I have a product attribute named "Versione" and used for variations. This attribute has two terms with slug: "digitale" and "cartaceo".
I would like to hide free_shipping:5 and flat_rate:3 shipping method rate IDs, when a product variation with "digitale" attribute term, is in cart.
I would like to hide free_shipping:4 shipping method rate ID, when a product variation with "cartaceo" attribute term, is in cart.
I've come across this code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ts_hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function ts_hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define the Product Attibute taxonomy (starts always with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_versione'; // Example for "Color"

    // HERE define shipping method rate ID to be removed from product attribute term(s) slug(s) (pairs) in this array
    $data_array = array(
        'flat_rate:3' => array('digitale'),
        'free_shipping:4' => array('cartaceo'),
    );

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ){
        if( isset($cart_item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]) ) {
            // The product attribute selected term slug
            $term_slug = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_'.$taxonomy];

            // Loop through our data array
            foreach( $data_array as $rate_id => $term_slugs ) {
                if( in_array($term_slug, $term_slugs) && isset($rates[$rate_id]) ) {
                    // We remove the shipping method corresponding to product attribute term as defined
                    unset($rates[$rate_id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

Hide WooCommerce shipping methods based on the variation product attribute, answer to my previous question, didn't work.

You can try like this
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ts_hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function ts_hide_shipping_method_based_on_variation_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return $rates;
    }

 // Define the product attribute taxonomy (starts with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_versione';

    // Define shipping method rate IDs to be removed based on product attribute term(s) slugs
    $data_array = array(
        'flat_rate:3'    => array('digitale'),
        'free_shipping:5'=> array('digitale'),
        'free_shipping:4'=> array('cartaceo'),
    );

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if ( isset( $cart_item['variation']['attribute_' . $taxonomy] ) ) {
            // Get the selected product attribute term slug
            $term_slug = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_' . $taxonomy];

            // Loop through the data array
            foreach ( $data_array as $rate_id => $term_slugs ) {
                if ( in_array( $term_slug, $term_slugs ) && isset( $rates[$rate_id] ) ) {
                    // Remove the shipping method if it matches the product attribute term
                    unset( $rates[$rate_id] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}

Admin Check: The function first checks if it's running in the admin area (unless via AJAX) to avoid interfering with backend operations.
Taxonomy Definition: The taxonomy pa_versione corresponds to the product attribute "Versione". Ensure that this matches the attribute used for your product variations.
Shipping Method Mapping: The $data_array maps the shipping methods to be hidden (flat_rate:3, free_shipping:5, free_shipping:4) based on the variation term slug (digitale, cartaceo).
Cart Items Loop: The function loops through each item in the cart to check if it has the specified variation. If a match is found, the corresponding shipping method is removed.

It doesn't work. How can I check if i'm doing sth wrong?

Make sure the shipping method IDs is correct. Also you can debug the codes to better understand where is the issue.
